# Click checkbox with js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I have a problem with .click() function.
I want to active checkbox on page load (using javascript) and that checkbox will active some functions for product sorting. The problem is ".click()" functions only mark checkbox (without calling functions), but when I click on the checkbox everything works fine.

```
var globalID = getQueryVariable("id");
console.log(globalID);

var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("jet-checkboxes-list__input");

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {

    if(classname[i].value == globalID) {
        classname[i].click(); // <=======================================================!!!!!!!
        break;
    }
}

function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
    }
    return(false);
}
```

Comment: how these functions will be activated? what event they are listening to (on your checkbox)? onchange?

Comment: What function are you expecting to run? And how is it triggered?

Comment: We might need to see your event handler for the `click` on the checkbox. It's possible the event is binded after you do your `click()`.

Comment: the problem is i don't know how those functions work because the functions are inside plugins and page is created with elementor.

Comment: https://ibb.co/1qH3WbZ these are probably sorting functions. I use jet smart filters plugin to sort products.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution.

this function and timer `setTimeout(function(){ eventFire(classname[i], 'click'); }, 500);`

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    var canceled = !el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    if (canceled) {
      // A handler called preventDefault.
      console.log("automatic click canceled");
    } else {
      // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    } 
  }
}
```